# Display a Continuously Changing List in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm using Java Swing (Eclipse) to create a GUI and want to be able to display a continuously changing list in a panel. In my code this is a LinkedList of Objects and it will automatically reorder and change without any need for user interaction. What are the options for displaying  this kind of list in the GUI? Thanks

Comment: See [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Answer (score 1):

One option, which I personally have used, is to have a method on the object containing this list, which, when called, modifies the data in the list, and then calls `updateUI()` which causes the UI to update without any user interaction.  In order to detect whenever this list's data changes (I'm assuming you're looking at something external to the program) I would poll using another thread.  The method you'd have on the object containing the list would have to be `synchronized` of course.

I hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

A Swing JList can take 3 types of collections as input.

1. An Object array - `public JList(Object[] listData)`
2. A Vector - `public JList(Vector listData)`
3. A ListModel - `public JList(ListModel model)`

You're going to have to convert your LinkedList into one of these 3 collections.

My recommendation is the ListModel.  You can use a DefaultListModel, extend the AbstractListModel, or write your own class using the ListModel interface.

Answer (score 0):

It is a very popular task when designing UI. To achieve your goals you need to follow next principles

1. Update your data in list
2. Send notification to UI Thread for update UI, here is a [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) to good tutorial

When to much data updates you need to **limit** amount of UI updates to acceptable *(1 per 100 mills or smth)*, otherwise UI will suffer